# sumar un entero a una variable tipo date con php

Tags: php

Tengo una variable de tipo entero `$numero` (dinámica), la cual necesito se sume a mi variable de tipo date `$fecha`.

Como resultado debiera darme lo que se muestra en mi variable `$fecha_sumada` que se muestra abajo en imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien conoce el método para lograr realizar esta operación en php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes logar lo que quieres convirtiendo tu string a date asi:

```
<?php
$fecha = "2019-11-28";
$numero = 60;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha. ' + '. $numero. ' days'));

?>
```

Comment: olvide mencionar que mi variable $numero es dinámica.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.